# Undefined reference with std::experimental::optional despite symbol being present

Tags: c++, c++14, undefined-reference, libstdc++, stdoptional

After fiddling with a bunch of CMake settings in a project I'm working on, I'm encountering a linking issue which I didn't previously experience.

In a nutshell, I have a static library (`.a` file) with the following symbol (demangled):

```
00000000000018e0 g     F .text  0000000000000690 std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int> monetdb::gdk::buffer_pool::find_column<(monetdb::column_name_kind)2>(monetdb::column_name<(monetdb::column_name_kind)2> const&) const
```

but when I try to link an executable with this file and a compiled source using that method, I get:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x6950): undefined reference to `std::experimental::optional<int> monetdb::gdk::buffer_pool::find_column<(monetdb::column_name_kind)2>(monetdb::column_name<(monetdb::column_name_kind)2> const&) const'
```

This is the single and only linking error, even though I instantiate a `buffer_pool` and use a bunch of other methods. On the other hand, this is also the only templated method the class have.

What are the potential causes for such an this error, given the existence of the symbol in the library?

My only "clue" so far is, that the name of the optional class is different: `std::experimental::optional` vs `std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional`. Could this be the cause?

Notes:

- I'm asking about *potential* causes, not the *actual* cause (which you can't determine without a self-contained example).
- I explicitly instantiate this templated method, just to be on the safe side.
- Compilation used g++ 8.3.0, and `/usr/bin/ld` is 2.32.51 .
- I'm on Devuan 3 Beowulf (~= Debian 10 Buster without systemd).
- Result of `g++- v`:

  ```
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=g++-8
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
  OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
  OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
  Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
  Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 8.3.0-22' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-mutex
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-22)
  ```

Comment: It would be nice to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would improve the question to contain a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the compilation command used. (If you can reproduce using `g++` commandline on a single file that will make things much easier since nobody can really tell what your cmake might be doing)

Comment: @ZhengQu: Yes, it would... but I asked about _potential_ causes, not _actual_ causes. Let me clarify that.

Comment: @M.M: There you go.

Comment: Did you use the same compiler and settings for building all the libraries involved?

Comment: This is off-topic without an MRE imo (and low-effort)

Comment: Pure speculation, but possibly your static library and executable are using different versions of the `<experimental/optional>` header.  The static library version seems to be older and has parked all that experimental stuff into the inner `fundamentals_v1` namespace that your executable build does not.  Can you rebuild the static library, ensuring the same compiler version and include paths?

Comment: @M.M: To my knowledge, I have used the same compiler and settings - but maybe 1021ProgramAlarm is right.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Did such a change happen in libstdc++ at some point? Say... between versions 8 and 9 perhaps? Because my system's default compiler is GCC 9.2.1 .

Comment: Experimenting on Compiler Explorer shows that recent versions of gcc (I spot checked 6.1 thru 9.3) will map `std::experimental::optional<int>` to `std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int>`.  I don't know what you could be doing in your executable build that would change that.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: ... but I do - see my answer. Thanks to you, I solved the mystery :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: _"given the existence of the symbol in the library?"_ But that isn't a given. It's not true at all, because those symbols are obviously not the same. If the linker says it needs symbol `abcd` and you see `abd` in the library, **that's the cause of the error**. The linker and `nm` are telling you the exact symbol names. If they don't match, **that's the cause of the error**.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: 1. It was "given the existence of the symbol I listed". 2. It is not entirely obvious to everyone (e.g. it wasn't to me) that the symbols are incompatible, even if not literally identical. 3. The mismatch was not the cause of the error, it was a symptom of the error. Or if you wish - it was the immediate cause, not the deeper cause.

Comment: The linker requires symbol names to be identical. Two symbols that look similar but are not identical are **different symbols**. Period.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr: This may be caused by using a custom `optional` implementation in the code outside the library.

My hunch was valid, but @1201ProgramAlarm's comments led me to the solution:

The definition of `std::experimental::optional` in the project using the static library wasn't taken from the standard C++ library. Instead, that was shadowed by [Andrzej Krzemieński's optional implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional). Now, I have nothing bad to say about it - it's really nice; however, it does put that definition into `std::experimental`, which means that if you're not careful you can mistake it for C++14's `std::experimental::optional`.

In my case, the chain of `#if __cplusplus > something` define it one way, `#else if __cplusplus > something else` define it another way etc. was faulty - The custom optional implementation was used even when compiling with C++14.

The linker, on the other hand, doesn't confuse the different `optional` implementations; in fact, libstdc++'s `std::experimental::optional` is just an alias for `std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<int>`; so the mangled name for a function returning an `optional<int>` is different. Thus even though in C++ you can't overload a function on the return type, i.e. no two functions can have the same signature except for a different return type - there's nothing preventing two mangled function names from being that way (IIANM), and that's indeed what happened in my case.

What I am not entirely sure about now is how I avoided the linking problem in the first place...

Comment: For function templates the return type is included in the mangled name. For non-template functions it isn't, so if you'd had a non-template function returning an `optional` then it probably would have linked and had silent undefined behaviour (for violating the one-definition rule).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is it possible to get visibility on that with a compiler flag?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Visibility on what? The undefined behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I mean, visibility on the fact that two functions are to be linked which differ only on the return type and aren't templates.

Comment: It might be detectable using `-flto` and might be detectable using the `gold` linker and   its option like `--detect-odr-violations` (or something like that). But in general, no. The reason it's undefined and not ill-formed is that it's not possible for the implementation to reliably detect it and give an error. If it was possible, it would be required to issue a diagnostic and not just result in silent undefined behaviour.